# Extending a javascript object during the objects instantiation

Tags: javascript, class, object, inheritance, prototype

I have a library of javascript classes that inherit from each other using John Resig's simple Javascript inheritance library (http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)
One of my classes (let's call it *parent*) has a number of child classes (*parent.child1*, *parent.child2*, etc) that extend the *parent* class and add their own methods.
Normally, I would instatiate a child object by

```
ob=new parent.child1(ops)
```

However, when I instantiate a *parent* object, the creation options hash can include a member called *type*, which tells me that this object must actually be a *child* object.

```
ob= new parent({type:"child1"});
```

During the object creation, how can I make sure that the object created is an instance of *parent.child1*? If that is not possible, how can I make sure that at least the created object has all the methods and properties of `parent.child1.prototype`?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: A better example is to have a class called *employee* and then two classes that inherit from *employee* called *employee.engineer* and *employee.admin*

Comment: If you instantiate a parent then it shouldn't be a child. It sounds like your parent constructor is doing too much.

Comment: maybe the parent/child names are wrong choices. Let's call the first class _employee_ and the other classes _employee.engineer_ and _employee.admin_. I want to create an _employee.admin_ instance by calling `new employee({type:"admin"})`. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
function Parent(options) {
    if(options.type) return new Parent[options.type]();
}
Parent.prototype.foo = 'foo';
Parent.Child = function() {
    this.bar = 'bar';
};
Parent.Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Parent.Child.prototype.constructor = Parent.Child;

var obj = new Parent({type:"Child"});
obj instanceof Parent;       // true
obj instanceof Parent.Child; // true
obj.constructor;             // Parent.Child
obj.foo;                     // 'foo'
obj.bar;                     // 'bar';
```

Comment: This is exactly what John Resig's library does in the Class.extend medhod that allows me to extend classes. With this library, when a new object is istantiated, it automatically calls the init method. It is within the init method that I want to create the child object. Do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
var ob = new parent[type]( ops );
```

Also, read about factory methods, or the factory pattern:
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Oriol's suggestion, I came up with the solution:
This is the part of John Resig's library that corresponds to the class' constructor:

```
 // The dummy class constructor
function Class() {
  // All construction is actually done in the init method
  if ( !initializing && this.init )
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

I modified this slightly:

```
 // The dummy class constructor
function Class() {
  // All construction is actually done in the init method
  if ( !initializing && this.init ){
      var ret=this.init.apply(this, arguments);
      if(ret) return ret;
  }        
}
```

Now in my *employee* class *init* method I start with:

```
init:function(ops){
  if(ops.type)
     return new employee[ops.type];
  //rest of init method
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Better create a separate function for this, like `makeEmployee` or so which chooses the constructor to call.